# Parse XML file - can't get all elements

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I have this [XML](http://pastebin.com/q64L3ECX).

I need to get both `test_set_name` and `test_case_name` or in other words, I need the 3 `test_case_name` but also the corresponding `test_set_name` where they belong. I need this using xPath but I can get only one element.

The import is to be made in a drupal site but I think this issue is not related with Drupal itself. I use a module for the parsing that asks me for the `Context` and all the fields that I want to get. I tried `/report/test_sets` as Context but I only get the first test_case_name of each test_set.

Do I have to do it in two steps?

I want to get this data (2 `test_set` and 3 `test_case`):

```
xpathparser:0 :
<test_set_name tl_label="Name" tl_name="name" tl_physicalname="CY_CYCLE">GUI.00 Launch Applications</test_set_name>
<test_set_name tl_label="Name" tl_name="name" tl_physicalname="CY_CYCLE">GUI.02 EM NE.000 EM NE Generic.Generic EM NE tests</test_set_name>
xpathparser:1 :
<test_case_name tp_label="Test Name" tp_name="name" tp_physicalname="TS_NAME">Launch TNMS</test_case_name>
<test_case_name tp_label="Test Name" tp_name="name" tp_physicalname="TS_NAME">Open</test_case_name>
<test_case_name tp_label="Test Name" tp_name="name" tp_physicalname="TS_NAME">ManualNetworkScan</test_case_name>
```

I'm using `Feeds` module in Drupal. Here is the xPath Parser Settings:
[image]

Comment: What programming language are you using? Where are you "getting" the values *to*? Without more information, this question doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I need to import the xml in a drupal site but I think this issue is not related with Drupal itself. I use a module for the parsing that asks me for the "Context" and all the fields that I want to get. I tried "/report/test_sets" as Context but I only get the first test_case_name of each test_set. That is my problem.

Comment: Put yourself in the place of someone reading this question who knows nothing about what you are trying to do; what answer are they going to be able to give? How are they to guess how this module can be used if you don't name it? Now [edit] the question so that somebody reading it has enough context to actually help you. Include what you've got so far, the current output, the expected output, a sample input (in the question, not behind a link that might die later) etc

Comment: Why do you think it's not related to Drupal? If somebody answered you with some Java code, would it be any use to you?

Comment: Because I can't get both information I need in one step or is the context or field names that are not correct and those 2 reasons are related only with the xml and parser itself. PS: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

XPath has a "union" operator, `|`, which can effectively combine the results of two expressions.

The following XPath expression will select all `test_set_name` and all `test_case_name` elements in a  document:

```
//test_set_name|//test_case_name
```

Given the information currently given in the question, that is as far as anyone can help.

Whether this will work in the unnamed module you're using, and how you can retrieve the data you want from those nodes and line it up usefully, I have no way of knowing. Nor do I know what is meant by "context" and "fields" in this situation (an XPath expression is evaluated against a "context", which is a particular XML node, but your question implies the context is itself an XPath expression, implying some other meaning).

Comment: Thanks IMSoP. The module is "Feeds". I didn't said that because this was not a drupal related question. If I did, someone would say: why don't you ask this at drupal site? I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I added the xPath Parser Settings in Drupal to help understand the problem better.

Comment: IMSop, the "union" operator partially solved my problem. In drupal the import now creates 5 nodes, 2 with the test_set and 3 with the test_case. I think now it's a drupal issue because I need to have only 3 nodes and associate the information.